# Why are there black lines between my sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, texturepacker

I have a single pixel sprite. To this sprite I add four sprites, each a quarter of a square. To offset the sprites, all i do is change their anchor points.

For example:

top right square is at anchor: (0,0);
bottom right : (0,1);
bottom left : (1,1);
top left : (1,0);

I expected the sprite edges to meet perfectly so that it looks like one big square. Instead there are black lines between the edges of each square so it looks like I have placed four squares close together.

I use texture packer to create a sprite sheet, containing the various squares.

Is there some setting in cocos2d-x or some code I must change to get the sprites to align perfectly ?

Edit: This is for cocos2d-x 3.1.1 and higher. Changing the anchor point is necessary and unavoidable.

EDIT: I use sprite frames from a sprite sheet created using TexturePacker. This was the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: I had the same problem in 3.2 but adding extrusion to the sprite sheet did not help. I was displaying the same sprite from a sprite sheet several times in a tile pattern. Each one had dark edges. All were children of the same SpriteBatchNode. I solved the problem by no longer using a SpriteBatchNode, since the new renderer in 3.2 can do that by itself, only using sprite sheets for packing data in the app. Doing this, the dark edges disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has something to do with using a sprite sheet (created using TexturePacker) to hold the pieces together. When you place the frames from the sprite sheet together to form a complete image the lines appear.

You can make the black lines disappear by setting the "Extrude" option in Texturepacker to at least 1.

EDIT: For those of you updating sprite positions based on a physics simulation, black lines can be caused by "sub pixel" positions. Try to either move your objects by complete pixels. Or search for answers with "sub pixel" for other solutions.

Comment: This is the right option if you are using texture packer. Worked for me

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

casting positions calculations to int type didn't help ?

Generally after certain float calculations like multiplying and divide and then complier auto demoting to to int may result in variation of 1px.

for example 26.500123 can be treated as pixel 26 or 27, depending to your casting methodology.

Test Case:

Are you saying you did this ?

```
auto testNode = Node::create();
auto s1 = Sprite::create("Images/1.png");
s1->cocos2d::Node::setAnchorPoint(Point(1,0));
auto s2 = Sprite::create("Images/2.png");
s2->cocos2d::Node::setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));
auto s3 = Sprite::create("Images/3.png");
s3->cocos2d::Node::setAnchorPoint(Point(1,1));
auto s4 = Sprite::create("Images/4.png");
s4->cocos2d::Node::setAnchorPoint(Point(0,1));
testNode->addChild(s1);
testNode->addChild(s2);
testNode->addChild(s3);
testNode->addChild(s4);
testNode->setPosition(Point(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2));
this->addChild(testNode);
```

and you got 1px gap ? i did that same with cocos2dx 3.1

i got this fine lady
[image: screenshot of rendering by iPhone 5]

Comment: I don't calculate positions, since the sprites are child nodes placed at the origin. The only difference between the sprites is the anchor points.

Comment: Added results from my test case to my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a 1px gap, but there are definitely noticeable black lines

Comment: Actually yes - I've done that. But I still get the lines. Although I don't use a Node as you've done - I use a single pixel sprite, and add the quadrants to it at the specified anchor point.

Comment: Also - I use sprite frames from a sprite sheet instead of individual files like you.

Comment: I tried attaching the quadrants to a node instead - but same result. Black lines between the quadrants.

Comment: I figured out the problem - it has to do with using sprite sheets with texture packer. I added my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't change anchorPoint, you'll regret it later. Calculate the correct position for each sprite.
2. Make sure the position x/y are on pixel boundaries. Casting to int will do the trick though Retina devices allow for 0.5 positions as well due to pixel density being 2x the point resolution.

Point #2 is also why you shouldn't use anchorPoint because you can't cast the position to integers when offsetting the texture with the anchorPoint.

Comment: Nope, it is not. Never. You can always express a change in anchorPoint through position and contentSize calculations. The only thing that anchorPoint does change is the center for rotation and scale operations, but even then you can use algorithms to change that without having to change anchorPoint. Either way, if you do change anchorPoint, you will only be able to fix the black line issues by manually going through each sprite every update and cast the position down to integers - and even that may not work depending on how and where cocos2d applies the anchorPoint calculation.

Comment: Changing the anchor point is necessary in my project. I believe the purpose of being able to change the anchor point is precisely so you can rotate the sprite around a specific point.

Comment: It is, though the question is: do you want to easily rotate but have black lines, or do you want to get rid of the black lines even if that means applying rotation manually?